# strpos not finding one word in a string

Tags: php

In the following code, if I set `$what` to 'red', it doesn't find it, whereas it finds green and blue. Why and how to make it find red as well?

```
$where = 'red,green,blue';

$what = 'blue';

if (strpos($where, $what) == true) {
    echo 'found';
}
```

Comment: Please read the big red box and the examples on the [manual page for `strpos`](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: If I change == to === it doesnt find anything anymore, not just red (if that's what you meant).

Comment: Because `strpos` also never returns `true`, so `=== true` will always be false. Again, please read the actual documentation and examples.

Comment: Why only 4 downvotes? This properly formatted and clear question deserves at least 10 downvotes IMO! Hehe, ridiculous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strpos` returns the index of the found string. In this case the index is 0 and your check for `== true` will fail. Try:

```
strpos($where, $what) !== false
```

The [documentation](http://uk.php.net/strpos) provides more information.

Answer (score 1):

strpos will return false if your string isn't there. Otherwise, it returns the position of your string.

In this case, 'red' is at the start of the string, which means that it's at position 0; and 0 evaluates to false.

You need to do a boolean compare on the result:

```
if(strpos($word, 'red') === false)
```